# Как составить SQL запрос?

Tags: sql

Имеется две базы данных: Студенты и Ведомости. Студенты содержит типичные данные такие как ФИО и т.п. Ведомости хранят данные о попытках сдачи экзамена, в запросе будет использован только параметр Оценка. Необходимо вывести студентов, которые никогда не получали на экзамене 3 или 2. Изначально я составил вот такой запрос:

```
   SELECT Студенты.Код, Студенты.Фамилия
    FROM Студенты INNER JOIN Ведомости ON Студенты.Код = Ведомости.Код_студента
    WHERE (Ведомости.Оценка<4)
    GROUP BY Студенты.Код, Студенты.Фамилия
    HAVING ((Count(*))=0);
```

Но он не работает, буду признателен, если мне укажут на ошибку, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Студенты.Код, Студенты.Фамилия
   FROM Студенты
   WHERE
      Студенты.Код NOT IN (SELECT Код_студента FROM Ведомости WHERE Оценка < 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
SELECT Студенты.Код, Студенты.Фамилия  FROM Студенты 
except
SELECT Студенты.Код, Студенты.Фамилия
FROM Студенты INNER JOIN Ведомости ON Студенты.Код = Ведомости.Код_студента
WHERE (Ведомости.Оценка<4)
```

Ваш запрос тоже можно исправить:

```
SELECT Студенты.Код, Студенты.Фамилия
    FROM Студенты LEFT JOIN Ведомости ON Студенты.Код = Ведомости.Код_студента
    WHERE (Ведомости.Оценка<4)
    GROUP BY Студенты.Код, Студенты.Фамилия
    HAVING ((Count(Ведомости.Код_студента))=0);
```